# How to handle a button press inside react-navigation titlebar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am pretty new to react-native and I am currently handling navigation for my app using react-navigation.
I want to be able to add a button to my app's title bar created by react-navigation and be able to press a button to call a function.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation;
    return {
      title: 'Assign To',
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          title='Back'
          onPress={() => params.handlePress()}
        />
      ),
    };
 };
```

This is close to what I read from the [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers), but it I keep getting an error of `undefined is not an object`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ handlePress: () =>   this.myFunction.bind(this) });
}
```

I have `myFunction` defined inside my component as follows

```
myFuntion() {
    //...
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Change `const { params } = navigation;` to  `const { params } = navigation.state;`

Comment: @bennygenel : I get an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.myFunction.bind' )`

Comment: Change `handlePress: () =>   this.myFunction.bind(this)` to `handlePress: () =>   this.myFunction()` since you are using arrow function you don't need to bind it

Comment: Thanks a lot now all working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this, with a little more explanation. The problem as you know was that you were combining the syntax of two similar approaches. You can use either the .bind syntax: `handlePress: this.myFunction.bind(this)` *or* the so-called fat-arrow syntax: `handlePress: () => this.myFunction`. They are more-or-less equivalent and there are opinions that the fat-arrow syntax supersedes the bind syntax (and, as always, opinions to the contrary :) ). There are differences, such as (quoting from [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/513)):

- Arrow functions are always anonymous, which means you can't, for
  instance, reliably call them recursively (since you don't have a
  reliable lexical name to use).
- Arrow functions actually create
  lexical bindings for this, super, and arguments. Only this is bound
  by .bind(..).
- Arrow functions cannot be used in new expressions,
  while bind(..) bound functions can.

Also, given that this is a react native question, it might help to be aware of this interesting article:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Answer (score 0):

For most elements you can use the onPress() function in react-native

`onPress={() => { Alert.alert("You clicked me") } }`

If you need to bind you can usually do it with the following example:

`onPress={this.functionName.bind(this)}`